# How do I get JUnit Tests? It is not under file>new?

Tags: java

Hi I want to create a JUnit test class but when i go to file>new there is no option for it. I can choose a project etc but thats not there. What am I missing? It's also the same result when I right click my package, it is not there. Thanks

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try File > New > Other > Java > JUnit if using `eclipse`.